# C++ Compare Length - Signal Sigabrt

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I have been watching many tutorials, but am still pretty new and am just messing around trying to get familiar with it. I am testing comparing string lengths but I am having a few issues. Here is the code.

*EDIT: The [10] in the 'cin' is still giving the error when fixed.
The error is Thread 1: Signal Sigabrt - if I change the > to a < then it works... But its not what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[10];
    cout<<"What is your name? ";
    cin>> name;
    if(strlen(name)> 11){
        cout<<"Sorry we only handle names less than 10 letters";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/upiMP.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: does this have anything to do with signal sigabrt?

Comment: Your next job is to look at `std::string`. In your current framework, don't forget about the *null-terminator*.

Comment: Your `return 0;` should be outside of `if` statement.

Comment: Where should the return 0; be, sorry im new to coding.

Comment: The check `if(strlen(name)< 11)` is redundant. When it's true it's already way to late to do anything and your code should crash before it (if you are lucky).

Comment: So you have a space that can only contain absolutely positively no more than 10 things, and then fill it with unknown number of things, and then count these things and check if you have less than 11? Doesn't make much sense. The space *always* has less than 11 things, it only has a room for 10. You should have counted the things when filling your space, not after you have finished.

Comment: Two other offences are: (1) if you have `char name[10]` then you only can fit a 9-character string in it, because you always need a space for a terminating character; and (2) your check is reversed (the complaint says that the string is too long, but you fire it when it's *too short*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm agreeing with Serge, as far as the strings go.

I'll go one step further and give you an example of using `std::string` to accomplish your goal. I recommend you look into it and use it as your go-to type for arrays of characters.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UtMU7D3g_s#t=121 (I didn't watch the whole thing, but it *might* be a good place to start)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    if(name.length() > 11){
        cout<<"Sorry we only handle names less than 10 letters";
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `cin>> name[10];` does **not** what you expect.

As `name[10]` is a `char`, you ask to take one single char from `cin` and to put it in `name[10]`, one position beyond the end of the array (last valid position would be `name[9}`) !

What you want is probably :

```
cin.width(10);
cin >> name;
```

which asks to take at most 9 characters from `cin` and put them in name followed by a terminating null.

EDIT :

Your last edit fixed the `[10]` error, but you still have a problem. If you let user input more than 10 characters in a buffer of size 10, you will have undefined behaviour since you will overwrite memory that might contain other variables.

The only foolproof way is to limit the input with the `width` method before inputting a char array.

But the really `C++` way would be to use a `std::string` where the size and allocation are managed by the `string` class itself..

EDIT 2 :

Here is a simple example that still uses char arrays and safely guarantees the input value to be less than 10 characters  by allowing one more and testing it is not used :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char name[11];
    cout<<"What is your name? ";
    cin.width(11);
    cin >> name;
    if(strlen(name)>=10){
        cout<<"Sorry we only handle names less than 10 letters";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the same using a `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    cout<<"What is your name? ";
    cin >> name;
    if(name.length() >=10){
        cout<<"Sorry we only handle names less than 10 letters";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do I still declare the variable 'name' by doing char name[10]; If possible can you post a fixed version I dont fully understand.